# Read RSSI value of all BLE devices on range

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, estimote, rssi

I am doing an aplication that needs to meassure the signal strenght of all BLE beacons(estimote) to process through a neural network, i want to store that RSSI in an array that will be sent to a server implemented in C#, i've already implemented it with wifi and want to obtain a similar result, here is my code for Wifi:

```
 ListaWifi = ObjWifi.getScanResults();
    rssi = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        rssi[i] = ListaWifi.get(i).level;
    }
```

Also i want the data to always have the same order:

```
int[] ret = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
            switch ((BSSID[i])) {
                case "9c:d6:43:94:ee:3f":
                    ret[0] = rssi[i];
                    break;
                case "9c:d6:43:94:f1:63":
                    ret[1] = rssi[i];
                    break;
                case "9c:d6:43:94:f1:99":
                    ret[2] = rssi[i];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
  }
```

Is there a way to continuosly monitor this data of BLE beacons and store in the same way as done with wifi??

Answer (score 1):

I think the RSSI value is included in the advertising packets.  I don't know any C#, so I can't help you with the specifics of getting that value from the packet (but it should be possible).

However, you're second stipulation that they always come in the same order would require some messing around.  Those advertising packets are broadcast over the air in no particular order and multiple times (the beacons don't communicate with each other and coordinate their packets).  One solution you could do is listen for a fixed period of time, collect all the ad packets together, then sort them by address (you'll probably get multiple from the same address, so maybe average the RSSI values).  I have no idea why you require them to be in the same order, so that may not be the best solution to the problem you haven't stated.